# Transparent .png affects printed color?

Tags: dompdf

Here's a strange issue for everyone!

I am working on a site that creates a pdf printout of the webpage.  It uses dompdf to render the html into a pdf.  I have a png image of a transparent box that gets filled in depending on the users "score."  So if they scored a 4, then four little boxes are filled in.

The color that fills in the boxes is set with a background-color in css.  When I download the pdf, the color matches the key, which is just a static image.  When I print out the downloaded pdf, the filled in boxes are NOT the same color!

One strange thing I noticed is if I remove the png image, the color matches the key as it is supposed to.

Any ideas?
-JB

Comment: Do you have a sample (HTML and PDF) you can share? This probably has to do with color spaces, which are difficult to synchronize across devices. Not to mention that the colors as defined via CSS and in the PNG may not quite match up, and how a device deals with a vector object (background-filled div) vs a bitmap object can vary.

Comment: Turns out it had to do with the background.  Css wasn't the problem because the two colors were in png images.  The difference is that one png had no transparency, the other one did.  Made all the difference.

Comment: That was what I was wondering. Without color management profiles embedded in a file you can see surprisingly varied color output. If you're trying to match colors it's best to use the same source (e.g. CSS or re-used images).